# Why can I have required parameters after a splat in Ruby but not optional ones?

Tags: ruby, arguments

This is possible in Ruby:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(a, *b, c)
  end
end
```

but this is not:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(a, *b, c='anything here')
  end
end
```

Why?

Edit: This question does NOT have an answer. In the answer linked, the first answer is:

> The splat means "use up all of the remaining arguments" but then you
>   provide an optional argument, so how could the interpreter know if the
>   last argument is part of the "numbers" splat or the optional
>   "options"?

Which is NOT a valid answer because according to this logic, Ruby would also not allow mandatory parameters after a splat.

Comment: It's an interesting question. I would assume it's because the splat could already contain all your optional variables. Plus you can pass the optional parameter before. So I don't really see how this could be an issue. Still interested in official explanation if such a thing exists :P

Comment: In the latter case: `SomeClass.new(1, 2)` => `b == [2], c == 'anything else'` or `b == [], c == 2`?

Comment: If you put default parameter after a splat, there will be no way to know when you want to override the default and when you don't because the last argument can always belong to the splat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173034/optional-argument-after-splat-argument

Comment: The question linked DOES NOT have the answer needed there, see my edit.

Comment: @daremkd This question has been answered both in http://stackoverflow.com/q/17173034/123527 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/13960678/123527, either in the accepted answer or in one of the other answers. The short answer is **you can't**, the long answer is explained in the links I just posted. One of the links I posted uses as an example `options = {}`, a parameter with a default value, which is the same case you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's argument binding semantics are already pretty complex. Consider this method:

```
def foo(m1, m2, o1=:o1, o2=:o2, *splat, m3, m4, 
          ok1: :ok1, mk1:, mk2:, ok2: :ok2, **ksplat, &blk)
  local_variables.map {|var| [var, eval(var.to_s)] }.to_h
end

method(:foo).arity
# => -5

method(:foo).parameters
# => [[:req, :m1], [:req, :m2], [:opt, :o1], [:opt, :o2], [:rest, :splat], 
#     [:req, :m3], [:req, :m4], [:keyreq, :mk1], [:keyreq, :mk2], 
#     [:key, :ok1], [:key, :ok2], [:keyrest, :ksplat], [:block, :blk]]
```

Can you tell at first glance what the result of the following invocations will be?

```
foo(1, 2, 3, 4)

foo(1, 2, 3, mk1: 4, mk2: 5)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, mk1: 5, mk2: 6)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, mk1: 6, mk2: 7)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, mk1: 7, mk2: 8)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, mk1: 8, mk2: 9)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, mk1: 9, mk2: 10)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, k3: 13)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, k3: 13, k4: 14)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
      ok1: 9, ok2: 10, mk1: 11, mk2: 12, k3: 13, k4: 14) do 15 end
```

Now, imagine adding optional parameters with default arguments after the splat parameter to that list. It's not impossible to find sane semantics for that, but it may lead to some non-obvious results.

Can you come up with simple, sane, backwards-compatible, and non-surprising semantics?

BTW: here's the cheatsheet for the method at the top:

```
foo(1, 2, 3, 4)
# ArgumentError: missing keywords: mk1, mk2

foo(1, 2, 3, mk1: 4, mk2: 5)
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 4+)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, mk1: 5, mk2: 6)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: :o1, o2: :o2, splat: [], m3: 3, m4: 4, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 5, mk2: 6, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, mk1: 6, mk2: 7)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: :o2, splat: [], m3: 4, m4: 5, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 6, mk2: 7, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, mk1: 7, mk2: 8)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [], m3: 5, m4: 6, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 7, mk2: 8, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, mk1: 8, mk2: 9)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5], m3: 6, m4: 7, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 8, mk2: 9, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, mk1: 9, mk2: 10)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 9, mk2: 10, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, k3: 13)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, ksplat: {k3: 13}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, k3: 13, k4: 14)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, ksplat: {k3: 13, k4: 14}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
      ok1: 9, ok2: 10, mk1: 11, mk2: 12, k3: 13, k4: 14) do 15 end
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, ksplat: {k3: 13, k4: 14}, 
#      blk: #<Proc:0xdeadbeefc00l42@(irb):15> }
```