# Ruby required argument assignment logic: how does the ordering works?

Tags: ruby

in Ruby, required arguments have the highest priority when they are being assigned in method. Example:

```
arg_demo(a, b, c=1, *d, e, f)
```

here, a,b,c,e,f have higher priority than array of arguments *d.

when we call this:

```
arg_demo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

the corresponding parameters are: `a=1, b=2,c=3, *d=[4,5,6], e=7,f=8`.
In this case, the *d gets its parameters assigned as the last one.

If that is the case, how does Ruby know to assign **e to 7**, and **f to 8** (as if "reserving" the **4,5,6** to the lower priority *d)?

Comment: How else could it assign those parameters into that definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby provides a great deal of flexibility in how a method's arguments are defined. She cannot read your mind, however, so she'll raise an exception if the assignment of arguments to variables is incorrect or ambiguous. The basic rule is that Ruby can work out how the values passed to a method should be assigned to arguments if and only if you can work that out yourself, and conclude that there is only one way it can be done (subject to Rule 4 below). We can formalize this with the first three rules below.

If these rules are satisfied, it should be obvious from the discussion how the values passed to the method are assigned to arguments, though Rule 4, which is not obvious, is also needed.

- Rule 1: required arguments must be preceded or followed by zero or more required variables, and nothing else (i.e., they must be stacked at the beginning and/or end of the list of values passed to the method).
- Rule 2: If all of a method's arguments are required or have default values, the number of values passed to the method must be between `n` and `n+m`, where `n` is the number of required arguments and `m` is the number of arguments with defaults.
- Rule 3: A splatted argument cannot precede a splatted argument or an argument with a default value.
- Rule 4: If an argument `a` with a default value is followed by a splatted argument or another argument with a default value, and the above rules are satisfied, the first value passed to the method that has not already been assigned to a preceding argument is assigned to `a`.

**Assignment of arguments to required variables**

Ruby first checks that there is exactly one way that required arguments can be assigned to their associated variables.

Here are some examples where Ruby gives a thumbs-up.

```
def meth(w,x)
  [w,x]
end
meth 1,2
  #=> [1,2]
```

I gave the above for completeness.

```
def meth(w,x,*y,z)
  [w,x,y,z]
end
meth 1,2,3,4,5,6
  #=> [1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6]
meth 1,2,3
  #=> [1, 2, [], 3]
```

`w` and `z` are the first and last arguments, and `x` is preceded by one or more required arguments and nothing else.

```
def meth(w,x=1,y,z)
   [w,x,y,z]
end
meth 1,2,3,4
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
meth 1,2,3
  #=> [1, 1, 2, 3]
```

`w` and `z` are the first and last arguments, and `y` is followed by one or more required arguments and nothing else.

Now some examples where Ruby finds the assignment of variables to arguments is ambiguous, and therefore raises an exception (at compile-time).

```
def meth(*x,y,*z)
  [x,y,z]
end
  #=> syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

The reason is obvious.

```
def meth(w,x=1,y,*z)
  [w,x,y,z]
end
  #=> syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Ruby doesn't know if `x` should equal its default or the second value passed to the method, which affects both `y` and `*z`.

Note that if the first (last) argument is required, the first (last) value passed to the method is assigned to that argument.

This establishes Rule #1.

**When all arguments are required or have default values**

```
def meth(w,x,y=3,z)
  [w,x,y,z]       
end
meth 1,2,3,4
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
meth 1,2,3
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 3] 
meth 1,2
  #=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 3..4)
meth 1,2,3,4,5
  #=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 3..4)
```

This establishes Rule #2.

**Non-required arguments**

If the method passes the test for required arguments, we can remove the associated variables from the argument list and then determine if Ruby would be happy with what's left (since the required arguments are stacked at the beginning and/or end of the argument list).

Two examples:

```
def meth(*w,*x)
end
  #=> syntax error, unexpected *

def meth(*w,x=1)
end
  #=> syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
```

This establishes Rule #3.

**Remaining possibilities**

Consider an argument with a default value that precedes either a splatted argument or another argument with a default value.

```
def meth(w=1,x=2,*y)
  [w,x,y]
end
meth
  #=> [1, 2, []] 
meth 3
  #=> [3, 2, []] 
meth 3,4
  #=> [3, 4, []] 
meth 3,4,5
  #=> [3, 4, [5]] 
meth 3,4,5,6
  #=> [3, 4, [5, 6]] 

def meth(w=1,x=2)
  [w,x]
end
meth
  #=> [1, 2] 
meth 3
  #=> [3, 2] 
meth 3,4
  #=> [3, 4]
```

We see that the first values passed to the method will be assigned to the arguments with the default values. If no values are passed to the method both variables will be assigned to their default values.

This gives us Rule 4.

**Design decision**

Note that the Ruby monks could have decided to raise a compile-time exception for `def meth(w=1,*x)` and/or a run-time exception for `def meth(w=1,x=2)` when only one value is passed, but chose not to do so.

**Common practice**

As a matter of common practice, one nearly always sees the required arguments (if any) listed first, followed by arguments with default values (if any), followed by zero or one splatted arguments. There is no loss of functionality by ordering the variables in that way.

Comment: You may want to steal this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27060893/2988 ;-)

Comment: @Jörg, beautiful example. I see the question was closed, but no upvotes until the one I just left! Such is life. Many of my answers that I consider to be pretty darn good have garnered no upvotes. Still, I gained knowledge and satisfaction writing them, as I'm sure you did (the latter anyway).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks that's a great answer. but could you pls point out, why in your 2nd example
 `(def meth(w,x,*y,z)
  [w,x,y,z]
end
meth 1,2,3,4,5,6
  #=> [1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6]`,
`z` chooses the value of 6, rather of 3(I know it's not logical, but I want to understand the mechanics of it). 

`*y` here is optional, and if only three arguments are provided, `*y` will return an empty array. So, `z` has the higher priority in "choosing" the argument. So why does `z` chooses the **one at the end** (i.e. 6, left-most)?

Comment: Anton, if the first (last) argument is required, the first (last) value passed to the method is assigned to that argument. That's just the way it is, but having those anchors provides tremendous versatility.

Answer (score 2):

1. Positional arguments at the beginning are bound to mandatory positional parameters at the beginning left-to-right
2. Positional arguments at the end are bound to mandatory positional parameters at the end right-to-left
3. The remaining positional arguments are bound to optional positional parameters left-to-right
4. Still remaining positional arguments are gathered into an array and bound to the splat parameter

If there are arguments left over, but no parameters to bind them to, or there are mandatory parameters with no arguments to bind to them, that's an `ArgumentError`.

Note that the above only describes the binding precedence **in my own words**, but *not necessarily* the order of evaluation. I'm pretty sure that you cannot refer to the value of mandatory positional parameters at the end in the default argument value of an optional positional parameter, for example.