# Dealing with 3 or more default arguments Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments, default

I've seen a few examples of passing default arguments when creating methods, but none of them seem to address if you want to substitute only the first and third argument... here's an example

```
def foo(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
    puts [a, b, c]
end

foo(1, 2) 
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

When I try to assign a=5 and c=7 and keep b its default value like this:

```
foo(a=5,c=7)
```

I get

```
=> 5,7,3
```

but I expect `5,2,7`

what is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: `foo(a=5, c=7)` yields the same result as `a=5; c=7; foo(5, 7)`. Ruby obviously doesn't know that you intend to assign `5` and `7` to the local variables `a` and `c` in the called method and assign `b` to its default value. She can only assume that you have passed the values of the first two variables, `a` and `b`, and that `c` is to be assigned its default value.  There is simply no way to do that other than by using named arguments. Note that the variables `a`, `b` and `c`  when executing the methods are unrelated to the local variables within the method that have same names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using keyword arguments?

```
def foo(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)
  puts [a, b, c]
end

foo(a: 5, c: 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've seen a few examples of passing default arguments when creating methods, but none of them seem to address if you want to substitute only the first and third argument...

That's because it is impossible.

Default arguments get bound left-to-right. I wrote more about how arguments get bound to parameters in an answer to these questions:

- [Mixing keyword with regular arguments in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20634180/2988)
- [Why can I have required parameters after a splat in Ruby but not optional ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27060893/2988)